# `A circular dependency has been detected (property key: "${key}")

Tags: nestjs

'sample entity'

```
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  Entity,
  Index,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToMany,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

import { ChannelChats } from './channelchat.entity';
import { ChannelMembers } from './channelmember.entity';
import { Channels } from './channel.entity';
import { DMs } from './dm.entity';
import { Mentions } from './mention.entity';
import { WorkspaceMembers } from './workspacemember.entity';
import { Workspaces } from './workspace.entity';
import { Users } from './user.entity';
@Index('name', ['name'], { unique: true })
@Index('url', ['url'], { unique: true })
@Index('OwnerId', ['OwnerId'], {})
@Entity({ schema: 'sleact', name: 'workspaces' })
export class Workspaces {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'int', name: 'id' })
  public id: number;

  @Column('varchar', { name: 'name', unique: true, length: 30 })
  name: string;

  @Column('varchar', { name: 'url', unique: true, length: 30 })
  url: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date | null;

  @Column('int', { name: 'OwnerId', nullable: true })
  OwnerId: number | null;

  @OneToMany(() => Channels, (channels) => channels.Workspace)
  Channels: Channels[];

  @OneToMany(() => DMs, (dms) => dms.Workspace)
  DMs: DMs[];

  @OneToMany(() => Mentions, (mentions) => mentions.Workspace)
  Mentions: Mentions[];

  @OneToMany(
    () => WorkspaceMembers,
    (workspacemembers) => workspacemembers.Workspace,
    { cascade: ['insert'] },
  )
  WorkspaceMembers: WorkspaceMembers[];

  @ManyToOne(() => Users, (users) => users.Workspaces, {
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn([{ name: 'OwnerId', referencedColumnName: 'id' }])
  Owner: Users;

  @ManyToMany(() => Users, (users) => users.Workspaces)
  Members: Users[];
}
```

'base.dto', which will be excented for other dtos.

```
export class JoinRequestDto {
  email: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    example: 'sun',
    description: 'nickname',
    required: true,
  })
  nickname: string;
  password: string;
}
```

'other entities'

```
export class UserDto extends JoinRequestDto {

  @ApiProperty({
    required: true,
    example: 1,
    description: 'id',
  })
  id: number;
}
```

" throw new Error(`A circular dependency has been detected (property key: "${key}"). Please, make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are using lazy resolvers ("type: () => ClassType").`);
^
Error: A circular dependency has been detected (property key: "id"). Please, make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are using lazy resolvers ("type: () => ClassType").
"

I have been trying to do clone-coding of Slack. I get the rror. I guess it's not the problem with dto, it has something to do with entities. I've got 8 more entities. As they are a lot, I just shared one entitiy code of 8 entities. Could you help locate why??

Comment: Circular dependency errors are from relations between entities, you should show here the res of entities to see where is the problem.